# PC Win 7 Ultimate not booting, blue-screens, sudden restart, hangs up

Tags: windows-7, crash

Since 2 months I experience mysterious behaviour of my PC running Win 7 Ultimate:
Often I can't boot it at all: black screen (sometimes I need to try booting several times in a row) or blue screen (something like:'Windows must stop to prevent your system from being  corrupted'). Another time while working on Windows, system suddenly crashes: blue screen or black screen appears that needs hard reset or resets by itself.

Some hints:

- It all started with hot summer - I have lowered CPU rate from 3200Mhz to 2000Mhz
- 2 yrs ago had the same problem & reinstalling Win7 helped, reinstalling Win 7 now **did not** help
- "CMOS checksum bad" at boot screen
- I've tried to run 2 Live USB: Mint 19 and Zorin 12.4 - they hang when I choose them from boot menu, though back in time I did it succesfully several times (with Mint 17)
- I did run memtest86+ - RAM is OK
- I did run Hot CPU Tester - free options - was OK

PC specs: AMD Phenom II 955 on MSI 770-C45 with 4GB RAM and NVidia GTX 460

Please help!

Comment: You would need to debug (analyze) the windows crash dump files to find the culprit.

Comment: Sounds like a bad hard drive.

Comment: @ Moab @Appleoddity But why does Live Linux from USB fail then? Common sense suggests that neither hard disk nor windows have anything to do with it...

Comment: Because it’s a logical thing to test and takes much less effort than you have already put in to this. We don’t have all the details. I can think of more than one scenario where the hard drive would come in to play even under the scenarios you described. Did you wiggle your RAM chips while you were testing them? There are lots of things here that haven’t been confirmed as good and every good technician knows they have to take the info another person is telling them about a computer problem with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many things that could be causing this that I'm having a hard time deciding what you should check first.  I'm also tempted to tell you to *just take it to a computer tech you trust with lots of experience*.

If you can get to it, check the Windows Crash Dump, which might narrow down the search, but it might also be a red herring.  It only knows what it thinks is the problem.  I always start with a "hardware first" approach because of this.

So, I think I'll start with "the obvious".  Visually check your mobo and video card for any damaged components.  I've seen even solid state caps blow, when they are super cheap.

Reseat everything, after blowing out any dust.  This includes cables.  A loose SATA cable can cause weird problems.  It also includes your CPU, and apply new thermal paste, too.

I've seen memory have problems even when a mem test shows good, so start removing sticks and even swapping their sockets.  If you find a stick that doesn't have an issue, drop it into each slot to make sure all the slots are good.

Change your CMOS battery.  If it failed, again weird problems.  It's cheap enough that it might be worth it to completely rule it out.

Test or swap out your PSU.  A bad rail might be low-volting or not providing enough amps to something at a critical point, again causing weird problems.  I've replaced a PSU that was causing a weird clicking sound when scrolling the mouse.  IDK how it was it problem, but that was the only thing that fixed the issue.

Reset your CPU settings to factory settings.  You may have inadvertently chosen unstable settings.  On that note, make sure your fan is working correctly.  Even if it's spinning, it might not be spinning fast enough.  This may have caused permanent damage to your CPU, if it's been constantly overheating.

Run more diagnostics from [Hiren's Boot Disk](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or [UBCD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/).  Some of these diags can also diagnose Windows problems.

You may also want to run Bootrec.exe/FixMbr and Bootrec.exe/FixBoot from the Windows disc.  A boot sector virus could be an issue, so rewriting it (to be safe) is a simple way to get rid of it.

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/command-prompt-fix-issues-your-boot-records

I'm sure there's other things, such as the mentioned bad hard drive, but this should give you a good start.

Comment: +1 for your big effort to show so many possibilities. On the other hand this seems overwhelming & time costly - maybe it's just time to buy a new machine. The most mysterious to me are problems with running Live Linux. Doesn't that specify the problem more?? Anyway thank you very much!

Comment: @keindeo, using the Live Disk does seem to point to a hardware issue, rather than a software issue, but that's about it.  For example: even if you aren't loading/using a USB port and driver, a shorted port can cause issues for the loaded OS as well as a Live Disk.  The only real thing the Live Disk cuts out for possibilities is the loaded OS.  And yes, it is a large time sink and why I included the "seek professional help" bit.  Doing this much testing can take half a day just for the physical tests and several days for the diagnostics.

Comment: PS Sorry but too low reputation to give an up vote.

Comment: I'll try again with Live USB after disconnecting HDD and report on Sunday.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that moving RAM to other 2 slots solved the issue. It is running just fine! Honors go to Appleoddity. Thank all of you for help!